# Manually set 'forked from' to GitHub project

Tags: git, github, fork

My project A (hosted on GitHub) somehow (not sure how) forgot that it was originally forked from another open-source project B. By 'forgot', I mean, when creating a pull request, I cannot choose B as a target for sending the pull request. Is there some way I tell GitHub that A is a fork of B?

(I can create a PR by forking B into A', then merging A into A' and sending the PR from A' to B which naturally works but, naturally, I don't like it)

Comment: I think there are both git itself (as in your local clone) and github (as in the github website minus git itself) involved. It's hard to tell which parts you refer to. As a blind guess, it sounds like you only need to configure a remote `B` to `A` - in the git repo on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to turn an existing repo into a fork. You can permanently switch to `A'` and abandon `A`, it's a one-time procedure. And there is no need to merge `A` into `A'`; you can simply push the whole `A` into `A'` instead.