# Github: I have a fork of a fork.. can I make it a fork of the original repo instead?

Tags: git, github

I have the following scenario:

```
.../orig-user/repo   # the original repo
.../user2/repo       # a fork of above
.../user3/repo       # a fork of .../user2/repo
```

is there any convenient way to "re-home" `.../user3/repo` so it becomes a 'direct' fork of `.../orig-user/repo`?

Alternatively, is there a simple way for `user3` to stay updated without involving `user2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672714/manually-set-forked-from-to-github-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to allow user3 to push/pull from original repo :

[How do I change which GitHub project I forked from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749246/how-do-i-change-which-github-project-i-forked-from)

If you want to also change the "forked from ..." message in the repo :

[Manually set 'forked from' to GitHub project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672714/manually-set-forked-from-to-github-project)

Comment: I want to change the "forked from..". The answer in that link says I have to fork `.../orig-user/repo` into a new `..user3/repo2` and then push `.../user3/repo` onto the new `.../user3/repo2` before abandoning `.../user3/repo` and starting to use the new `.../user3/repo2`.  Did I understand that correctly? Will the method suggested by @sajibkhan not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can change/add  `remote` (say, `upstream`) that will indicate `/orig-user/repo`.

If your upstream already exists, then change that url with /orig-user/repo.

```
$ git remote -v      # see all the remotes
$ git remote set-url upstream <url-of-orig-user-repo>      # change the upstream url
```

---

Or, add a new upstream one.

```
$ git remote add <upstream> <url-of-orig-user-repo>    # Add new remote/repositories
```

Now when need to take the changes of `/orig-user/repo` repo just pull from `upstream`

```
$ git pull upstream master         # here, upstream is the remote of /orig-user/repo
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this will not change the "forked from.." in github (pull-requests from a fork-of-a-fork seem to be more challenging).

Comment: You're right. This will not change `forked from..`. So, in that situation you can re-fork a new repo from original and take your `user3` changes into it.